# how to compare two column values in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

i am trying to fetch two column using joins ,below query is working fine,now how i can compare these two values using if statement.

```sql
SELECT 
    failed = L.failed_attempts AS 'FAILED ATTEMPTS',
    s_value = s.setting_value as 'SETTING VALUE'
FROM login_t L
INNER JOIN settings_t S ON S.SETTING_NAME = 'login_attempts'
WHERE L.login_id = id  
  AND L.failed_attempts > S.setting_value;
```

if `failed_attempts > settings_value` then update the `is_logged_in` column value in `login_t` to 0 and return false otherwise return true

PS: i'm using mysql stored procedure

Comment: Your query is working with single quoted aliases?

Comment: yes its working fine

Comment: And this query always returns one row?

Comment: yes this always return single row with two column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your select statement allways retuns exactly one row, you can store the selected values `INTO` local variables, which you should `DECALRE` first. Then you can use `IF .. THEN .. ELSE .. END IF;`: To return something you just need to `SELECT someValue`.
I am not shure what exatly should be compared. But this is the way, you can do it:

```sql
DECLARE FAILED_ATTEMPTS INT;
DECLARE SETTING_VALUE   INT;

SELECT 
    failed = L.failed_attempts,
    s_value = s.setting_value
INTO 
    FAILED_ATTEMPTS,
    SETTING_VALUE
FROM login_t L
INNER JOIN settings_t S ON S.SETTING_NAME = 'login_attempts'
WHERE L.login_id = id  
  AND L.failed_attempts > S.setting_value;

IF FAILED_ATTEMPTS > SETTING_VALUE
THEN
    -- your update statement here
    SELECT FALSE;
ELSE
    SELECT TRUE;
END IF;
```

Maybe you need

```sql
SELECT 
    L.failed_attempts,
    s.setting_value
INTO 
    FAILED_ATTEMPTS,
    SETTING_VALUE
```

But somehow i guess you need two select statements:

```sql
SELECT L.failed_attempts,
INTO FAILED_ATTEMPTS
FROM login_t L
WHERE L.login_id = id;

SELECT s.setting_value
INTO SETTING_VALUE
FROM settings_t S
WHERE S.SETTING_NAME = 'login_attempts';
```