# How do I fetch two column values in mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

I have a column with different stored data (user, street, country).

What I am trying to do is the following:

```py
await cur.execute("SELECT street, country FROM dbname WHERE user=%s AND user=%s", (user1, user2,))
result = await cur.fetchone()
print(result)
```

So I am trying to print the two users and their street and country. The output is always empty or gives me an error. Is this even possible in that way? I have looked through many examples but have not found anything on my matter.

I also tried to use `fetchmany()` and `fetchall()` but still no result. Maybe I am overcomplicating some things here.

For reference, I have looked at the following pages:

1. [how to compare two column values in mysql stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514569/how-to-compare-two-column-values-in-mysql-stored-procedure)
2. [Mysql: Selecting values between two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824871/mysql-selecting-values-between-two-columns)
3. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/select-a-specific-value-between-two-column-values-in-mysql

A working solution could be:

```py
await cur.execute("SELECT street, country FROM dbname WHERE user=%s", (user1,))
result = await cur.fetchone()
print(result)

await cur.execute("SELECT street, country FROM dbname WHERE user=%s", (user2,))
result1 = await cur.fetchone()
print(result1)
```

However, I have to execute some code twice. Is this already bad practice or doable in some cases/not avoidable at some point?

Comment: Have you tried updating the SQL statement to `SELECT street, country FROM dbname WHERE user=%s OR user=%s`? The output is empty because a single row user cannot be both user1 and user2.

Comment: @JoeAkanesuvan This looks like a working solution. Do you know by any chance if this is also possible with the `UPDATE` method? E.g.: `("UPDATE dbname SET country=%s, country=%s WHERE user=%s OR  user=%s", (country1, country2, user1, user2,))` (Since it likely is a new question, there is no need to answer it)

Comment: If you're trying to set different `country` values for the different user then you should keep the `UPDATE` method as two separate calls.

I'm going to add my comment as an answer and we can close this out! Good luck with whatever you're doing @R6Winner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the SQL statement to `SELECT street, country FROM dbname WHERE user=%s OR user=%s`

The output is empty because a single row user cannot be both `user1` and `user2`